# How to implement incoming video call with flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm working on a video call application with flutter. For the calling part, I'm using Jitsi's API.

I'm trying to implement video call notification for the callee just like popular calling apps (e.g. if the user locked the screen, then display a full-screen notification with a ringtone; if the user is using the phone, then just show the notification with accept/reject option on top).

[image: Example of notification on lock screen]

There are many packages like callkeep, flutter_callkeep, connectycube_flutter_call_kit, etc. But they seem to be only for "call with phone number". I also searched through a lot of posts here, but I can't find good examples of how to implement incoming "non-phone-number" video calls. I'm open to use FCM as suggested in many posts

Is there a way to do this without using native code?

Answer (score -1):

One way to implement video calling is via using **Agora SDK**

Link --> https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtc_engine

Comment: Actually Agora is expensive so I would rather not use Agora

Comment: It has some free minutes that you can use, of course you have to use some service. You can't create a new service from scratch

Comment: Of course, that's why I'm using Jitsi :)